# Get list with special number in Lisp

Tags: list, lisp

I'm new to Lisp and I need to make function than can return second value of sublist which containts special number.

For example, I have function with two arguments: one of them is list with sublists and second is my special number which I'm going to search:

```
 (find_neighbours '((1 2) (3 1) (4 5) (9 1) (2 3) (1 5)) 1)
```

That function should return something like that:

```
(2 3 9 5)
```

Because we have sublists with 1 inside `(1 2) (3 1) ...`.

Here is my solution:

```
(defun find_neighbours (lst node)
    (if lst
        (cond 
            ((= node (caar lst))  
                (cons (cadar lst) 
                (find_neighbours (cdr lst) node))
            )
            ((= node (cadar lst)) 
                (cons (caar  lst) 
                (find_neighbours (cdr lst) node))
            )
            (T (find_neighbours (cdr lst) node))
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: I know @sds already answered, but you are expected to show some effort by showing the code you already have, things you have tried, places you have searched, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem this way:

```
(defun find_neighbours (lst node)
    (if lst
        (cond 
            ((= node (caar lst))  
                (cons (cadar lst) 
                (find_neighbours (cdr lst) node))
            )
            ((= node (cadar lst)) 
                (cons (caar  lst) 
                (find_neighbours (cdr lst) node))
            )
            (T (find_neighbours (cdr lst) node))
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple approach:

```
(defun other-end (edge vertex)
  "Return the other end of the EDGE if VERTEX is one of them or NIL."
  (destructuring-bind (beg end) edge
    (cond ((= vertex beg) end)
          ((= vertex end) beg)
          (t nil))))

(defun neighbors (graph vertex)
  "Return the list of neighbors of the VERTEX in the GRAPH."
  (loop for edge in edges
    for other = (other-end edge vertex)
    when other collect other))
```

There are other ways, e.g.,

```
(defun neighbors (graph vertex)
  "Return the list of neighbors of the VERTEX in the GRAPH."
  (delete nil (mapcar (lambda (edge) (other-end edge vertex))
                      graph)))
```

etc...